# WP Query Meta Value - How To Identify Specific, Unique Values?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, meta-value

On my Club Profile pages, I'm displaying a list of posts (Player Profiles) where the title of the specific Club Profile page is also a meta value contained in those Player Profiles against one or two keys: `Previous` or `Later`.

The WP query I'm using is:

```
$clubname = get_the_title();
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'players',
'meta_key' => 'last_name',  
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order'    => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'OR',
   array('key'=> 'previous',
         'value' => $clubname,
         'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
   array('key'=> 'later',
         'value' => $clubname,
         'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
   ),
$sharedplayers = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($sharedplayers->have_posts()) : while ($sharedplayers->have_posts()) : $sharedplayers->the_post();
```

This works in the vast majority of cases because most Club Profile titles are unique. There is at least one examples, however, where there's a value that appears *within* a longer value – i.e., **Cove** / **Cove**ntry City. As such, the list of Player Profiles on the Cove Club Profile is also (incorrectly) including player profiles containing Coventry City as a meta value.

After experimenting with the various compare operators (`LIKE`, `=`, and `REGEXP`), I'm still yet to find a solution where **Cove** is only identified as a meta_value in its own right, and not confused/conflated with **Coventry City**. Is it as 'simple' as factoring a space into the query? If so, how is this correctly done where the value is `$clubname`?

Comment: Could you please provide more examples of pairs that should match and pairs that should not match. I did not really understand what you want to achieve. Why are the `previous` and `later` meta keys not containing just the exact name. What do they actually contain? Also, did you try using `'value' => $clubname.' '`, which fits your "factoring a space into the query" request?

Comment: The only other example of this happening I have so far found is with **Vauxhall Motors** and **Vauxhall Motors (Luton)**. The `previous` and `later` meta keys don't just contain the exact name because, for each player, they will play for more than one club before or after. Finally, tried `'value' => $clubname.' '` without success.

Comment: I see, could you provide the full strings for the `previous` and `later` meta values for the case that is creating the problem? It would help to see how those values are separated (with comma, spaces, etc...). Also note that the "forced space" will not mach your value if the value is the last in the list. The cleanest solution would be to save all those `previous` and `later` values in different meta fields. (You can have multiple meta fields with the same key for the same CPT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Storing multiple values into one single meta entry, instead of storing each value on its own meta entry (which would be the optimal approach).

But still you can make it work that way.

According to [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/), for the WP Query match operator you can use:

> Possible values are ‘=’, ‘!=’, ‘>’, ‘>=’, ‘<‘, ‘<=’, ‘LIKE’, ‘NOT LIKE’, ‘IN’, ‘NOT IN’, ‘BETWEEN’, ‘NOT BETWEEN’, ‘EXISTS’

- If you go with the `=` operator, you will not get your expected results since you are storing the club name as a substring.
- If you go with the `LIKE` operator, you will get unwanted results if your Club Name is a part of another Club Name. As **Cove** and **Coventry**.

So a possible solution if you don't want to store the names as individual entries would be to force your checks by adding a separator to your `$clubname` variable.

**For example**:

```
'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'OR',
   array('key'=> 'previous',
         'value' => $clubname.',',
         'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
   array('key'=> 'later',
         'value' => $clubname.',',
         'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
   )
```

But this will only work if all of your club names do have a comma after it. Including the last name in the list!

It won't work with spaces because that would not detect the difference between *Vauxhall Motors* and *Vauxhall Motors (London)*

So, in this case, your meta value content should be:

"Whatever, something else, blablabla, Vauxhall Motors, other,"

But the real nice solution would be to have a meta field that contains the exact name, and then you can use the `=` with no issues.

Comment: Attempted both variations of adding wrapper spaces around the variable – but it still returns the same list. To explain further, `Previous` and `Later` are custom field text areas, with club names listed (new lines are rendered automatically with `<br>`). These names will match Club Profile titles. Perhaps I need to rethink how these club names are entered as meta values?

Comment: @PeteHayman Well, you can make it work that way too. It's just not a very optimal way and also it will take longer to request your database that way. The best solution would be to store each Club Name as an individual entity. Your CPT can have as many meta values with the same key as you like. But yeah, if you provide the full string of the value that is creating the issue we can think of a solution.

Comment: @PeteHayman I updated the answer with a possible working solution. Check it out and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: At the moment @Álvaro, the `Previous` or `Later` fields will contain data in the following example format: 
`Rushden & Diamonds (loan)
Wigan Athletic (loan)
Swansea City (loan)
Cambridge United
Coventry City` on separate lines (CPT adding a `<br>` tag on the front end) 

So, the list doesn't contain any commas or punctuation. But I can see from your example how that would work in practice. Which makes me think I will need to update the Player Profiles to include commas or similar to make the solution work as directed.

Comment: @PeteHayman you may want to try it with the comma or whatever other symbol you like and let me know if it worked. But yeah, there isn't any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: The solution has worked @Álvaro – I'll update the meta keys for all Player Profiles to reflect this.